# Powershell: Get Unique Objects in a two column array

Tags: powershell

I have a file with the following columns: *RecipientAddress* and *MessageId*

I need to get only conntent with unique *RecipientAddress*. If I run:

```
Import-Csv $File_MsgList | select RecipientAddress | Sort-Object RecipientAddress | Get-Unique -AsString
```

It filters out the duplicates correctly. But If I want to get the associated *MessageId* as well, it is not able to remove the duplicate addresses anymore.

```
Import-Csv $File_MsgList | select RecipientAddress, MessageId | Sort-Object RecipientAddress | Get-Unique -AsString
```

How can I get both columns as well as get uniques on the first column?

Comment: What do you mean with "unique RecipientAddress"? You may share some (sanitized) sample data from your csv file. (formatted as code as well, please.  ;-))

Comment: You may use `Group-Object` for this purpose. You'd get unique RecipientAddresses with their associated message IDs.

Comment: Do you want to display only pairs where _RecipientAddress_ occurs only once or do you want to display every _RecipientAddress_ only once? For the latter, is the _MessageId_ for every redundant _RecipientAddress_ the same? If not, which _MessageId_ is the desired one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because [`Get-Unique`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique) filters each unique item (object) including *all* its properties.
Instead you might simply use the `-Unique` parameter on the [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) cmdlet:

```
$MsgList = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
RecipientAddress, MessageId
a@domain.com,1
b@domain.com,2
b@domain.com,3
c@domain.com,4
'@

$MsgList | select RecipientAddress, MessageId | Sort-Object RecipientAddress -unique

RecipientAddress MessageId
---------------- ---------
a@domain.com     1
b@domain.com     2
c@domain.com     4
```

Comment: Thanks @iRon that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by two columns and get the unique entries based on each main column entry, which here is "name":

```
'name,number
joe,1
joe,1
john,1
john,1' | convertfrom-csv | sort-object name,number -unique

name number
---- ------
joe  1
john 1
```